# easy_install failure on windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, easy-install

I have created two eggs using bdist and egg_A is defines as a dependency  of egg_B.
I check both egg using the command *unzip* and both are ok, however when I try to insall the egg using easy_install I get the following stack trace :

Installed c:\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\pymarketdata-1.0-py2.7.egg
Reading file:C:/python_nest/
Processing dependencies for PyMarketData==1.0

**zipimport.ZipImportError: bad local file header in c:\yoan\yoyo\lib\site-packages\PyMarketData-1.0-py2.7.egg**

Any idea where it could come from ?

Answer (score 1):

This error:

> bad local file header

seems to say that the file header (which usually determines the filetype) isn't passing Python's test. It could be the zipping program you used.

Try 7-Zip (free) or a different program when creating your `egg`. I haven't made them before, but I think there is even a way to do it with plain 'ol Python.